# Maximum occurrence in sequence (advanced gaps and island problem)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to count maximum sequential occurrence of event with `flag=1` for each `hid` in `human`. Sequence is generated by date.

There is an example of my table:

```
    CREATE TABLE max_in_row
        ([hit_finish_dttm] varchar(13), [hid] varchar(13), [agent_login] varchar(57), [flg_no_talk] int)
    ;
    
    INSERT INTO max_in_row
        ([hit_finish_dttm], [hid], [agent_login], [flg_no_talk])
    VALUES
        ('2020-03-01', 'EQERR13', 'Dmitrii', 0),
        ('2020-03-02', 'EQERR13', 'Dmitrii', 1),
        ('2020-03-03', 'EQERR13', 'Dmitrii', 1),
        ('2020-03-01', 'RR13EQE', 'Dmitrii', 0),
        ('2020-03-02', 'RR13EQE', 'Dmitrii', 1),
        ('2020-03-03', 'RR13EQE', 'Dmitrii', 0),
        ('2020-03-04', 'RR13EQE', 'Dmitrii', 0),
        ('2020-03-05', 'RR13EQE', 'Dmitrii', 1),
        ('2020-03-06', 'RR13EQE', 'Dmitrii', 1),
        ('2020-03-07', 'RR13EQE', 'Dmitrii', 0),
        ('2020-03-01', 'EQERR13', 'Alex', 1),
        ('2020-03-02', 'EQERR13', 'Alex', 1),
        ('2020-03-03', 'EQERR13', 'Alex', 0),
        ('2020-03-04', 'EQERR13', 'Alex', 1),
        ('2020-03-05', 'EQERR13', 'Alex', 1),
        ('2020-03-06', 'EQERR13', 'Alex', 1),
        ('2020-03-02', 'RR13EQE', 'Alex', 1),
        ('2020-03-03', 'RR13EQE', 'Alex', 0),
        ('2020-03-04', 'RR13EQE', 'Alex', 1)
    ;
```

I expect to recieve at result next table:

```
Dmitrii | EQERR13 | 2
Dmitrii | RR13EQE | 2
Alex    | EQERR13 | 3
Alex    | RR13EQE | 1
```

I literally tried to overcome my problem with `row_number(order by date) - row_number(partition by human, hid, flag order by flag)`, but idk why it doesn't work.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your question is tagged Postgres but the sample code is SQL Server.

Comment: @GordonLinoff done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the individual groups using:

```
select hid, agent_login, count(*)
from (select mir.*,
             row_number() over (partition by hid, agent_login order by hit_finish_dttm) as seqnum
      from max_in_row mir
      where flg_no_talk = 1
     ) mir
group by hid, agent_login, dateadd(day, -seqnum, hit_finish_dttm);
```

Then aggregate the results one more time:

```
select hid, agent_login, max(cnt)
from (select hid, agent_login, count(*) as cnt
      from (select mir.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by hid, agent_login order by hit_finish_dttm) as seqnum
            from max_in_row mir
            where flg_no_talk = 1
           ) mir
      group by hid, agent_login, dateadd(day, -seqnum, hit_finish_dttm)
     ) ha
group by hid, agent_login;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4f255fdc6769a70ce6754b84d7335c37) is a db<>fiddle using SQL Server.  The code would be the same in Postgres except for the date functions, but your table creation code is for SQL Server.

Comment: Why do we need `dateadd(day, -seqnum, hit_finish_dttm)`? Is it possible to re-write `dateadd` function it for Postgres?

Comment: Is it possible to do the same in Postgres?

Comment: @VemenBusat . . . In Postgres, it is `hit_finish_dttm - seqnum * interval '1 day'`.

Comment: I got an error about type. Created table for Postgres (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b9aceac195fe112bfa830ce4640b4d96). If you have any ideas, will be thankful to listen them

Comment: @VemenBusat . . . Don't store dates as strings:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=aeb8eb3af749e40a3d3e5eef17f8f98c.